# ionic - salvar latitude e longitude na firebase

Tags: firebase, typescript, ionic3

Criei um projeto no ionic e gostaria que quando o usuario clicasse em "salvar localização", a posiçao de onde ele deixou o marcador ficasse salva no seu perfil de usuario no firebase, porém, nao tenho ideia de como pegar a latitude e a longitude do marcador e salvar na firebase, alguma solução???

```
      loadMap(){
        this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position)=> {
          let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude); // pegando localização atual

          let mapOptions = { //opções do mapa
            center: latLng,
            zoom: 15,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            disabledZoomDoubleClick: true,
            fullscreenControl: true
          }
          this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions); //adicionando mapa com as opçoes

          let marker = new google.maps.Marker({ //Adicionando marcador
          map: this.map,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          position: latLng,
          draggable: true,

        });

        let data = {
          lat: null,
          lng: null
        }

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event){ //Aciona quando o usuario clica no marcador
          data.lat = event.latLng.lat();
          data.lng = event.latLng.lng();
        });

        }, (error) => {
          console.log(error);      
        });      

      }

  addFirebase(){ //aqui é a função do botão que vai salvar a localização

  }
```

Comment: O que você já conseguiu fazer?

Comment: Como você pretende capturar a localização, por marcador, por nome do endereço..?

Comment: preciso capturar a localização do marcador no ponto que o usuario arrastou, ele é arrastavel

Comment: Entendi, poderia adicionar o código do seu mapa? É só editar sua pergunta e adicionar o trecho de código

Comment: certo, só um instante

Comment: só preciso que a localização do marcador que ele arrastou, fique salvo na firebase, quando clicar no botao "salvar localização" e vai chamar o "addFirebase()"

Comment: Vamos por partes, primeiro vc precisa pegar a latitude e longitude e depois salvar rs

Comment: certo kkk isso mesmo rs

Comment: Outra duvida, quando vc faz o click ele não ta executando a função addListener?

Comment: esse click foi so um teste que eu fiz, foi o mais perto que cheguei de pegar a localização do marcador

Comment: mas nao foi util pq nao consegui usar ele no "addFirebase()" que é acionado quando clica no botao

Comment: Beleza, quando eu chegar em casa monto um exemplo pra você.

Comment: ta ok, valeu mano

Answer (score 1):

Pra pegar sua posição em `Latlng` a partir do maker vc precisa implementar um `Listener` que será chamado toda vez que você arrastar seu marker. Note que na função eu estou esperando o evento de `dragend`, além desses você pode passar o `dragstart` e o `drag`, para saber mais leia a [documentação](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) Você pode criar essa função:

```
lastLatLng(marker) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', () => {
    this.LastLat = marker.position.lat();
    this.LastLng = marker.position.lng();

    const toast = this.toast.create({
      message: `Latitude: ${this.LastLat}\nLongitude: ${this.LastLng}`,
      duration: 6000,
      position: 'botton'
    });
    toast.present();
  });
}
```

Repare que eu criei duas variáveis `LastLat` e `LastLng`. Depois é só vc chamar essa função na sua função `loadMap` e passar seu marker como parâmetro.

Agora pra passar essas informações pro `Firebase` acho que daria pra fazer outra pergunta, com esse método vc já tem o `lat` e `lng` é só pegar essas variáveis na sua função que envia os dados pro firebase.

Demonstração do app funcionando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: muito obrigado, ajudou demais, vou testar

Comment: não sabia sobre essa função 'dragend'

Comment: @JuniorDosSantos tenta implementar e ve se da certo, se te ajudar vc pode marcar essa resposta como solução, assim outras pessoas com o mesmo problema vão ser ajudados.

Comment: O botao que voce criou "add Marker" chama a função lastLatLng???

Comment: Nao, o botão só adiciona um marcador em vez de carregar o mapa com um marcador